# How to play Local Radio in iTunes?

Tags: itunes, radio

My Office is located at Ahmedabad, Gujarat, India. (380013) (zip)

I want to play local radio's of ahmedabad.

Ahmedabad's most popular radios are

- 91.5
- 98.3

etc.

I don't know How to Add them?

If I go to iTunes & Radio Option, I am getting iTunes default listed Radios.

How to add own Radio channels? ( specially Local ones )

How to play them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your radio stations would have to provide an audio stream over the web.  If they don't do that then you're out of luck.

If they do provide an audio stream you'll have to find it.  Once you get the URL for the audio stream you can go into iTunes's Advanced menu, select "Open Audio Stream", and paste the URL in there.  As long as it's a standard format that iTunes can handle it should work fine.

Comment: best place to start looking is probably the local radio station's website.